# how to configure the url of an old @SOAPBinding @Webservice to work with spring boot 2.7 and deploy to jboss?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, jboss

I'm trying to modernize/convert an old SOAP web service to work with Spring 5 and Spring Boot 2.7, and eventually deploy to jboss 7. I've finally gotten through all the Spring Context errors (not finding beans to autoconfigure, etc.) so it will deploy successfully. But when I try to hit the url, it returns a 404. I haven't worked with SOAP/wsdl in a long time so I think I'm missing a mapping piece.

The url I'm using is `http://localhost:8080/PrintQueueDetailService`

I was trying to re-use as much as possible, so I was told that I could re-use the existing class which had the `@WebService` and `@SOAPBinding` :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/pdfrm/PrintQueDetail", name = "PrintQueDetailWSService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
@Service
public class PrintQueueDtlServiceImpl implements PrintQueDetailWSService {
    ....
}
```

Additional config, which I found I was supposed to add to 'wire' together the old code and new SpringBoot WS pieces, and which would do some magic servlet mapping behind the scenes:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PrintQueueApp.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter simpleJaxWsServiceExporter() {
        SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter exporter = new SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter();
        exporter.setBaseAddress("/PrintQueueDetailService");
        return exporter;
    }

}
```

More context: This is a multi-module maven project. 1 submodule is db/repos/services, 1 submodule is the SOAP interface with wsdl, where the cxf generation happens. And then the 3rd is the 'main' module, which has the main PrintQueueDtlServiceImpl that handles the SOAP calls.

This is being deployed to jboss 7. I'm just running and testing locally with some jboss/wildfly server inside IntelliJ. I noticed there is also this piece, within /webapp/WEB-CONFIG/jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/PrintQueueDetailService</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I'm still not clear on if or how the /webapp/WEB-INF is packaged under the 'new' spring boot. I'm packaging it as a .war in maven.